# Не сохраняются значения в базе данных

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Почему id_house и id_tenant у меня null, если я отправляю значения? Дата сохраняет корректно. Как мне задать того, кто арендует и какую квартиру. Вероятно, что я некорректно как-то обрабатываю, потому что в Entity у меня они указаны в качестве классов. В общем, не понимаю с чем конкретно связано.

Принимаю значения:

```
@PostMapping("/rent")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
    public void homeRent(@RequestBody Contract contract) {
        contractRepository.save(contract);
    }
```

Contract:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "contract", schema = "public")
public class Contract {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_house")
@ToString.Exclude
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private House house;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_tenant")
@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
@ToString.Exclude
@JsonIgnore
private User user;

@Column(name = "end_date")
private LocalDate end_date;
@Column(name = "start_date")
private LocalDate start_date;
}
```

Запрос через Postman:

```
{
    "start_date" : "2020-03-12",
    "end_date" : "2020-03-19",
    "id_house" : 2,
    "id_tenant" : 3
}
```

Comment: GenerationType.IDENTITY - авто генерация id, не надо задавать свой id

Comment: @AlekseiGaile а где я его задаю? У меня в Json запросе информацию о том, кто должен арендовать и какую квартиру

Comment: пардон. Вы должны добавить объект House и объект User в Contract , а не некие id сразу добавлять в Contract, либо передавать полностью сформированный json

Comment: Кажется, я понял про что вы говорите. Создаю ContractDto. Принимаю там ID, а дальше через findId ищу конкретную квартиру и пользователя по классам, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: возможно у вас еще и с каскадами проблема будет

Comment: @Санаев а почему с каскадами будут проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была легко решена, необходимо было сохранять именно классы, вот моя реализация:

```
public class ContractDto {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private LocalDate start_date;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private LocalDate end_date;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private Long id_house;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private Long id_tenant;

    public LocalDate getStart_date() {
        return start_date;
    }
геттеры, сеттеры..
}
```

Пример того, как сохранять:

```
 @PostMapping("/rent")
 @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user:write')")
    public void homeRent(@RequestBody ContractDto contractDto) {
    House house = houseRepository.findById(contractDto.getId_house()).orElseThrow();
    User user = userRepository.findById(contractDto.getId_tenant()).orElseThrow();
    Contract contract = new Contract();
    contract.setHouse(house);
    contract.setUser(user);
    contract.setStart_date(contractDto.getStart_date());
    contract.setEnd_date(contractDto.getEnd_date());
    
    contractRepository.save(contract);
  }
```